# Issues with async / await in C#

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

I'm using async / await methods in C#... my operations are to create databases on Azure Cosmos DB, the problem is when the code is runnnig, for any reason... the flow brakes without any issues apparently

can anyone help?

```
Task p= Run();

public async static Task Run()
{
    .
    .
    .
    await CreateDatabase(client)
}

private async static Task CreateDatabase(DocumentClient client)
{
    var databaseDefinition = new Database { Id = "MyDB" };
    var result = await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(databaseDefinition);
    var database = result.Resource;
}

//In second line, the code brake when the debugging is operating

//==> var result = await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(databaseDefinition);
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: [Are you calling `Wait` or `Result` anywhere further up your call stack?](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)